# Saving Lists to tables in subsonic 3.0

Tags: subsonic

I have been using subsonic 2.0 but have moved to subsonic 3.0

I want to create a list of my parent child objects and save in a batch rather than .Save() on each object

In subsonic 2.0 you could use batchsave() but I also want to do a deepsave() on each object to populate the relationships of the parent to child tables

Is this possible - and does someone have example code